# Valgrind complaining about call to fgets

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

I have this code:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * 150);
    char roomElements[150];
    char *roomSize = NULL;
    int i = 1;
    int *size = NULL; // does this need to be malloced?
    char input = '\0';

    check(argc == 2, "Please enter two arguments");

    fp = openFile((char*)argv[1], "r");

    initscr(); // ncurses
    noecho();


    /*Draws rooms and items*/
    while (fgets(buffer, 150, fp)) { // line 25
        removeNewLine(buffer);
        strcpy(roomElements, strchr(buffer, ' '));
        roomSize = strtok(buffer, " "); // get the room size
        size     = getRoomSize(roomSize, i); // convert room size to int pointer
        drawRoom(size, i); // draw the room
        tokenizeRoom(roomElements, i); // draw the elements
        i++;
        free(size);
    }

    /*This is the user input loop*/
    do {
        input = getch();
        getInput(input);
    } while (input != 'q');

    free(buffer);
    fclose(fp);
    endwin();

    return 0;
error:
    return -1;
}
```

Valgrind output:

```
==74014== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==74014== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==74014== Using Valgrind-3.11.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==74014== Command: ./bin/rogue assets/room.txt
==74014== 
==74014== Invalid read of size 32
==74014==    at 0x10043EC1D: _platform_memchr$VARIANT$Haswell (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib)
==74014==    by 0x10023080A: fgets (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib) 
==74014==    by 0x100000E10: main (main.c:25)
==74014==  Address 0x100918a40 is 32 bytes before a block of size 4,096 in arena "client"                                                       
==74014== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==74014==    at 0x10043EC7A: _platform_memchr$VARIANT$Haswell (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib)
==74014==    by 0x10023080A: fgets (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==74014==    by 0x100000E10: main (main.c:25)
==74014==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==74014==    at 0x100008601: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:303)
==74014==    by 0x100233836: __smakebuf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==74014==    by 0x100236E99: __srefill0 (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==74014==    by 0x100236F94: __srefill (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib) 
==74014==    by 0x1002307DA: fgets (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
```

What could I be doing wrong? Everything is initialized, I am at a loss. No other answers on this topic help me. I am not sure why it complains about the fgets call either.

2nd edit, I will show some more of my code.
Here is `openFile()`

```
FILE *openFile(char *file, char *mode) {
    FILE *fp = NULL;

    fp = fopen(file, mode);

    check(fp, "Could not open %s", file);

    return fp;
}
```

Here is `getRoomSize`

```
int *getRoomSize(char *size, int roomNum) { // rows x columns
    int row, col;
    char strRow[5], strCol[5];
    int *roomSize = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);

    check(roomNum < 7 && roomNum > 0, "Invalid room to be drawn");

    /*Convert string to int*/
    strcpy(strRow, strtok(size, "X"));
    strcpy(strCol, strtok(NULL, "X"));
    row = atoi(strRow);
    col = atoi(strCol);

    roomSize[0] = row;
    roomSize[1] = col;

    return roomSize;
}
```

EDIT 3: Here is my MCVE. It reproduces the conditional jump and uninitialized value errors:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char *buffer= malloc(sizeof(char) * 150);
    char roomElements[300] = {0};
    int i = 1;
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (!fp) {
        printf("no\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    while (fgets(buffer, 150, fp)) {
        strcpy(roomElements, strchr(buffer, ' '));
        i++;
    }

    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

The file is a `.txt` file containing this line 6 times: `15X20 dn2  de10      dw11       g4,2          m10,17 M12,7  M4,9 p11,14 w10,10`

Comment: (a) what happens when `strchr(buffer, ' ')` returns NULL?  (b) The call to  `getRoomSize` is suspicious but you didn't show the code for it; (c) "make sure your file pointer is malloced" doesn't make sense, there is no problem with with `FILE *fp` but maybe you had a bug in your `openFile` function; (d) don't cast `argv[1]`, fix the `openFile` interface instead ; (e) post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) next time as there are too many unknowns in this code.

Comment: I'd guess based on the valgrind message that the `removeNewLine` function also removes the null terminator

Comment: @MattMcNabb Sorry about the lack of info, I updated my post. Also the `removeNewLine` function just replaces `\n` with `\0`.

Comment: In a lot of places you do `strcpy` without length checks, and use the results of `strtok` or `strchr` without checking they are not null first. Clean all that up as you may have buffer overflows or dereferencing null pointers, which causes undefined behaviour. And post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with the file contents that cause the problem.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I added an MCVE.

Comment: it is not complete, the "MCVE" does not compile as posted. I guess you omitted some lines on purpose, but an important part of MCVEs is that they are *Complete*. I cannot reproduce your error yet so it is important that we both work on the exact same code before proceeding.

Comment: Also show the commandline you used to do the compilation;  and does the same valgrind output occur if you remove the `strcpy` and just write `strchr(buffer, ' ');` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be a false alarm.

`fgets` uses `memchr` internally to check if it's seen a newline yet. Your platform `memchr` is a highly optimized assembly routine (the name indicates it is specifically optimized for Haswell architectures) which reads 32 bytes at a time to locate the target character (probably using some SSE instructions to do so). At the end of your buffer, `memchr` runs off the end of your 150-byte allocation and valgrind complains.

This is totally safe; `memchr` can't possibly touch bad memory if it sticks to aligned 32-byte boundaries since the page allocation size is (at least) 4096 bytes. If it finds the target character in uninitialized memory, it will presumably detect that the located character is past the end of the string it was supposed to search, and return the correct result in that case.

I'd ignore this error. Valgrind does occasionally produce false positives; consider obtaining or making a platform-specific suppressions file to automatically ignore these kinds of false alarms.

Comment: Interesting! Is it safe to ignore all the errors then?

Comment: Well, you can probably ignore errors arising from `memchr` - specifically, the invalid read of size 32, the subsequent uninitialized jump error, and the informational malloc message afterwards. Other errors may yet be important - don't ignore everything!

Comment: Of course I won't ignore everything! I have a question I asked today that involves supp files, hopefully I can figure out how to make the supp file.

Comment: alternatively, you can make your buffer size a multiple of 4. That would stop valgrind from complaining about this specific issue.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: Nope, the buffer size would have to be a multiple of 32 (and there's no guarantee that would even suppress the issue, since your malloc may only guarantee 8- or 16-byte alignment). `memalign` would be the only way to guarantee the necessary alignment, and that's terrifically overkill for this simple program.

Comment: @nneonneo : bitten by byte-bit confusion lol. Good point as well about the malloc alignment.

Comment: @nneonneo : the valgrind error can then still be avoided by making the buffer 32 bytes longer than what you'll actually use. ie. create a buffer of size `182`, and pass `150` to `fgets`. Unless you're in a low-memory environment, that should not cause an issue.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: Yes, that would work, *provided* you initialized the buffer. Then again, all of these solutions are suboptimal in the sense that they involve doing weird non-obvious changes to the code, simply to avoid what is more-or-less a bug in an external tool...

Comment: This is interesting discussion, I am going to try my hand at making a supp file.